# Click action from cloned element does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Click action won't work on any cloned element.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q9m4t/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>hello <a class="del" href="#">del</a></li>
    <li>new <a class="add" href="#">add</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(".add").click( function() {
    $(this.parentNode).prev("li")
    .clone()
    .insertBefore(this.parentNode);
    return false;
});

$(".del").click( function() {
    $(this).closest("li").remove();
    return false;
});
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Click event on cloned element of same class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111105/click-event-on-cloned-element-of-same-class)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery .Clone() loses click event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753579/jquery-clone-loses-click-event)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `.clone()` with `.clone(true)`. This indicates you want to copy all event handlers over to the newly created cloned element. Read up more about this [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

**[jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9m4t/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

From the [jQuery `.clone()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents)

> Normally, any event handlers bound to the original element are not
>   copied to the clone. The optional withDataAndEvents parameter allows
>   us to change this behavior, and to instead make copies of all of the
>   event handlers as well, bound to the new copy of the element.
>   As of jQuery 1.5, withDataAndEvents can be optionally enhanced with
>   deepWithDataAndEvents  to copy the events and data for all children of
>   the cloned element.

So, adding **true** to the `.clone()` method will allow you to keep all events.

**.clone(true)**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `clone(true)` which will create a new handler for each clone, you could delegate the click event:

```
$("ul").on("click",".del", function() {
    $(this).closest("li").remove();
    return false;
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9m4t/2/)