# On click event not getting cloned

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Using jQuery 1.10 I'm cloning a div containing a button on which a click event is defined. The div gets cloned but not the click event.

I've seen this question asked many times (for example: [Click action from cloned element does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815211/click-action-from-cloned-element?lq=1) ) and all answers suggest to use `clone(true)` or `clone(true, true)`.

This does not seem to work in this case.

I've made a small working example: (FIDDLE LINK: http://jsfiddle.net/wD3dq/1/ )

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <a href=# " id="clickMe">Click Me to add a new Div</a>
    <div id="elementHolder">
        <div id="webThumb5">
            <p>Test1 <a href="# " class="del_button " role="button ">Delete</a></p>
        </div>
        <div id="webThumb6">
            <p>Test2 <a href="# " class="del_button " role="button ">Delete</a></p>
        </div>
        <div id="webThumb7">
            <p>Test3 <a href="# " class="del_button " role="button ">Delete</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divTemplate" style="display:none ">
        <p>Test <a href="# " class="del_button " role="button ">Delete</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#elementHolder div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0.2em;
}
```

JS:

```
var counter = 100;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#elementHolder a.del_button").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var parentDiv = $(event.target).parent().parent();
        alert("Id: " + parentDiv.attr('id'));
    });
    $("#clickMe").click(function (event) {
        counter += 1;
        var newId = "webThumb" + counter;
        var newDiv = $("#divTemplate").clone(true, true);
        newDiv.attr("id", newId).prependTo("#elementHolder");
        newDiv.fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use bubbling and not worry about cloning the events. `$("#elementHolder").on("click", "a.del_button", function() {});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not clone the event since there is no event to clone.

You never assign a click event to `divTemplate`, you only do it to elementHolder which divTemplate is not a child of.

Get rid of worrying about cloning the event and just use bubbling

```
$("#elementHolder").on("click", "a.del_button", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var parentDiv = $(this).closest("div");
    alert("Id: " + parentDiv.attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use even delegation:

```
$("#elementHolder").on("click", "a.del_button", function() {
   //do stuff
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wD3dq/2/